# Regex Not Catching Quote in IE

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble getting IE to play nice with my regex. I'm trying to grab the background image and use it elsewhere on the site. It works in every browser except IE (of course).

Here's the code:

```
var bgImg = body.css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"]*(.+)['"]*\).*/, '$1');
```

It really should work, but for some reason IE is not catching the last quote and is returning this:

http://mydomain.com/images/bg-image.jpg"

without the `replace` it would return this:

url("http://mydomain.com/images/bg-image.jpg")

Shouldn't my regex by taking care of that last double quote? How do I make IE play nice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex seems to work in IE.  It's a different approach:

```
/^url\(['"]*([^'")]+)['"]*\).*/
```

I'm not exactly sure why the other one didn't work, but it may have to do with the greediness of the *.

Yours fails for me in IE9 and this regex works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yyqB6/

Answer (score 0):

IE is correct. You are telling it to match any number of any character, followed by zero or more quotes, followed by a close bracket. IE is matching the last quote as part of the "any character", as it should, because the quantifier is greedy by default.

Try this regex:

```
/^url\(['"]?([^'"]+)['"]?\)$/
```

Next time, make sure your code is correct before dissing IE, kay?

Comment: Erm, considering I've been using it since IE4, am now on IE9 and have never once had any issues with it, yeah, I'm standing up for it.

Comment: I wonder why it works in multiple versions of Safari, Chrome, Opera, and Firefox, both Windows and Mac versions... I tested in each.

Comment: Because they don't include the optional quotes in their internal representation of the style. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to believe that other browsers aren't showing this correct behaviour. Your first capturing group  should always contain the quote because you've used a greedy quantifier, and you've made the closing quote optional.

I would suggest a different regex:

```
var bgImg = body.css('background-image').replace(/^url\((['"]?)(.+?)\1\).*/, '$2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't work for me in Firefox either.

This is because `.+` is greedy and consumes as much of the string as it can.

Try using `.+?` instead.

Answer (score 0):

check [browser type](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) if the type is IE then add one more regex for replace to select text inside quotes( s/\"//g) and finally perform whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe don't use a regex, and just use **substr**:

```
var bgImg = body.css('background-image');

bgImg = bgImg.substr(5, bob.length - 7);
```